# How do I add a .setHover class to parent li when ul has class showSubMenu?

Tags: jquery

```
<li id="SubnavGrpTwo" class=""><a id="item2_link" href="#">SomeLink</a>
    <ul class="showSubMenu">
        <li class="subFirst"><a>Submenu link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Problem is: How do I add a `.setHover` class to the parent `li` when `ul` has the class `showSubMenu`?

Many thanks in advance.

Samar

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure CSS

```
ul.showSubMenu li:hover {  }
```

**EDIT**

You want to add the class to the actual `ul` when the `li` is hovered.  The `parent` function should make this easy:

```
$("ul.showSubMenu li").hover(function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass("hoverClass");
}, function() {
   $(this).parent().removeClass("hoverClass");
});
```

Comment: Correct but I wanted to add .setHover on Parent LI.. e.g <ul><li class="setHover">somelink <ul class="showSubMenu"><li>submenu</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: Thus just add a .parent() to $(this) : `$(this).parent().addClass("hoverClass");` -- OK, this has been edited :-)

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie - exactly :)

Comment: Can I only add .setHover class to parent <LI> if nested UL has class .showSubMenu?

Comment: @user1071634 - yes - that's what the code above does.  It only selects ULs that have the showSubMenu class.

Comment: Thanks Adam. However, can i use IF condition for checking if <ul> has class .showSubMenu, Add class .setHover to it parent LI?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.showSubMenu > li').hover(function () {
      $(this).addClass('setHover');
   }, 
   function () {
      $(this).removeClass('setHover');
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually as simple as one line:

```
$('ul.showSubMenu:parent').addClass('setHover');
```

Of course this is not a good solution if you want to actually call this on hover. Just change it with "this"